# Invalid directory path error while connecting to database

Tags: csv, plsql, oracle11g, data-import

I am using oracle 11g and using sqldeveloper to run/edit queries.

My table is:

```
ID     FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME    MAJOR                 CURRENT_CREDITS
10008   A            Dd          Computer Science         2
10009   B            DD          History                  3
10010   D           dd           Computer Science         3
10011   C           ad           Economics                3
10012   D           Da           History                  3
10013   E           df           History                  3
```

Above table is in CSV format (lect.csv) stored in ‘D:\1Deepak\Data’..

I have created below procedure **to import the csv file in oracle**, but it’s not working getting **below error** :

> Connecting to the database r.
>
> ORA-29280: invalid directory path
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LOADLECTURER", line 39
>
> ORA-06512: at line 2
>
> Process exited.
>
> Disconnecting from the database r.

**Code :**

```
create user D identified by d 
CREATE DIRECTORY log_dir AS 'D:\1Deepak\Data'; 
Grant all privileges to D;
Grant Read, Write on Directory log_dir to D;

CREATE TABLE lecturer (
  id               NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name       VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name        VARCHAR2(20),
  major            VARCHAR2(30),
  current_credits  NUMBER(3)
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Loadlecturer
AS
p_TotalInserted number;
  v_FileHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  v_NewLine  VARCHAR2(100);  -- Input line
  myFirstName lecturer.first_name%TYPE;
  v_LastName lecturer.last_name%TYPE;
  v_Major lecturer.major%TYPE;
  v_FirstComma NUMBER;
  v_SecondComma NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_FileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('Log_dir','Lect.csv', 'r');
  p_TotalInserted := 0;
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(v_FileHandle, v_NewLine);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        EXIT;
    END;

    v_FirstComma := INSTR(v_NewLine, ',', 1, 1);
    v_SecondComma := INSTR(v_NewLine, ',', 1, 2);

    myFirstName := SUBSTR(v_NewLine, 1, v_FirstComma - 1);
    v_LastName := SUBSTR(v_NewLine, v_FirstComma + 1,
                         v_SecondComma - v_FirstComma - 1);
    v_Major := SUBSTR(v_NewLine, v_SecondComma + 1);

    INSERT INTO lecturer (ID, first_name, last_name, major) VALUES (1, myFirstName, v_LastName, v_Major);

    p_TotalInserted := p_TotalInserted + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(p_totalinserted);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
 Exception 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FileHandle);
    RAISE;
END Loadlecturer;
```

Could anyone help me in figuring out why above mentioned error is coming?

Comment: Does your Oracle **server** really have a directory `D:\1Deepak\Data`?

Comment: Is Oracle running locally on your PC? A common mistake is to expect utl_file on the database server to read files on your desktop.

Comment: `UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('Log_dir',...` should probably be `UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('LOG_DIR',...` - ie. the directory name needs to be in upper case.

Comment: @William Robertson yes oracle is installed locally on laptop

Comment: Does @Boneist suggestion solve a problem or at least change error to another?

Comment: btw where does "unable to connect to database" come in?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  I edited the title.

Comment: Better, but it doesn't look like you have a database connection issue at all. If you did, your procedure wouldn't run. Your issue is the `ORA-29280: invalid directory path` error (which is probably fixed by Boneist's suggestion).

Comment: @Boneist and @ william Robertson... i tried but still same error come in..basically server is installed locally on laptop and i am creating user as mentioned above in my code (i tried using upper case but still not working)  ..

Comment: Your procedure is created by and stored in in the "D" schema? Does the O/S user that your database is running under have privileges to read the file in D:\1Deepak\Data? Also, make sure you reference the exact filename (case sensitive) in your code.

Comment: @Boneist ..your suggestion worked well.. thanks all for the suggestions